# How to instance generic parameterized class

Tags: java, generics

I just implement a `MapBuilder` to build map easy,
But when i try to get an instance of HashMap.class,I suddenly found that I can't use HashMap.class to get such an instance.

It's illegal!

So can anybody tell me why and how to solve this problem?

The MapBuilder is follow:

```
import java.util.Map;

public abstract class MapBuilder {

    public static <K, V, T extends Map<K, V>> InnerMapBuilder<T, K, V> start(
            Class<T> clazz) {
        return new InnerMapBuilder<>(clazz);
    }

    public static class InnerMapBuilder<T extends Map<K, V>, K, V> {

        private T target;

        public InnerMapBuilder(Class<T> clazz) {
            try {
                target = clazz.newInstance();
            } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

        public InnerMapBuilder<T, K, V> put(K key, V val) {
            target.put(key, val);
            return this;
        }

        public T get() {
            return target;
        }
    }
}
```

And the test code is below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String, String> v = start(HashMap<String,String>.class).put("a", "b").get();
    System.out.println(v);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to obtain a parameterized class type variable for a generic type, as Reimeus has said.  So you have three choices.

First, you can live with the unchecked cast:

```
Class<? extends Map<String, Integer>> clazz = 
    (Class<? extends Map<String, Integer>>) HashMap.class;
```

Second, you can *reify* the parameters for a class by extending it (in this example, using an anonymous inner class):

```
Class<? extends Map<String, Integer>> clazz =
     new HashMap<String, Integer>() {}.getClass();
```

Or third, and best, just take the `Map` instance instead of a class in `start()`.  You're not saving the user any work by taking the `Class` rather than an instance of `Map`, and the first thing you do is create an instance of it.

By passing it in, the user can even tweak the settings of the map (e.g. for a `HashMap`, set the load factor, for `TreeMap`, specify the `Comparator`) so it's a better alternative anyway.  If you need to, you can assert that it's empty when it's passed in.

If for some reason you really need a factory, don't use `Class`: it doesn't work well as a factory, because the only way you can customize the instance that `Class` creates is by subclassing the class and providing a new no-arg constructor.  Just create an interface `Factory<T>` that has a method `T create()` and then accept a `Factory<? extends Map<K, V>`.

Comment: Thanks for good answer, I'll take some time to think about your words.

Answer (score 0):

First since `start` takes a class you would have to pass it an unparameterized class such as `HashMap.class`. Second, as you're returning a generic type `Map`, you would have to make your local type match also, so to use:

```
Map<String, String> v = start(HashMap.class).put("a", "b").get();
```

Comment: thank you , but this should not be type safe and will get some generic type warnings

Comment: Yes but you can't define a parameterized class type variable.